# Changing the style of a Combo-Box in WPF (in Blend preferably)

Tags: wpf, combobox, controls, styles, expression-blend

I'm having some issues trying to change the look / style of a combo box in Expression Blend / WPF.  While there are tutorials out there describing setting styles for buttons, there seem to be a few wrinkles with ComboBox controls.

Can anyone offer any advice, or point me towards good tutorials that cover re-styling something more complex than a button?

Answer (score 3):

The **ComboBox** style template has 3 parts to it.

The **ContentPresenter** you should have come across styling Buttons.

There is a **Part_Popup** that you should find easy to change properties on and style.

The last part is a **ToggleButton**, to style that you need to "edit a copy" again and create another new style template for the ToggleButton.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BeaCostas SolarSytem Listbox](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=40) it's a lovely piece of work.