# Want to style the comboboxes and scroll bars in my application

Tags: wpf, combobox, controls, styles, expression-blend

I've got Expression Blend 4 installed on my machine.  I just need to know what I'm doing.

My application will be running on a laptop equipped with a touch screen, in police cars where the user will probably be driving the car.  Needless to say, the interface has to be easy to use.  In this case, that means things like the drop down buttons on ComboBox controls and scroll bars need to be wider than normal so they're easy for the driver to use.

Can someone tell me what part I have to change for each of these controls in order to get the effect I want?  I tried editing a copy of the template for one of the combobox controls in one of my user controls and playing with the ToggleButton control but that didn't do what I wanted it to do.  There's so much mark-up in the template it's hard to tell what's doing what.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Tony

Edit:

I figured it out from the first answer to [this previous StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490294/changing-the-style-of-a-combo-box-in-wpf-in-blend-preferably).  I had to make a copy of the ComboBox's style, then make a copy of the ToggleButton's style.

Thanks anyway.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to edit the application in Expression blend.  I clicked on one of the ComboBoxes and right clicked.  From the context menu, I selected Edit Template | Edit a copy.  In the dialog box that appears, I specified that the new template should be applied to all ComboBoxes in the application.

Within the ComboBox's style, there's a ToggleButton.  I repeated the above steps with the Togglebutton.  Finally, I changed the width to make it what I wanted.  There's also a path in there for the arrow that you can play with if you like.

Tony